# Create a new column based on an absolute reference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created an SQl Query that gives me the results below

```
Product| Qty.Sold | Total Value
----------------------------    
Men    | 585      | 4750
Wom    | 927      | 9235
Child  | 587      | 6023
```

I need to create 2 additional columns next to Total Value.

**For the new column 1** 
**Formula is** first value of Qty.Sold/Sum of Qty Sold.The same applies for corresponding rows(Wom,Child..)
Eg : 585/2561,927/2561....

**For the new column 2** 
**Formula is** first value of Total Value/Sum of Total Value.The same applies for corresponding rows(Wom,Child..)
Eg : 4750/25726,9235/25726...

How Can I write a sql query to accommodate this new change

Comment: use can get this by generating row_number ,then after use that row number in your new column formula

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like this:

```
SELECT product, qty, value,
        qty/(SELECT SUM(qty) FROM tbl) AS qty_ratio
        value/(SELECT SUM(value) FROM tbl) AS value_ratio
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

So something like this:

```
SELECT Product,Qty_sold,total_value,
       Qty_sold/(select sum(Qty_sold) FROM (Your query here)) as Col1,
       total_value/(select sum(total_value) FROM (Your query here)) as Col2
FROM (Your query here)
```